# How to get the list of Nitro system based EC2 instance type by CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#ec2-nitro-instances) lists up the instance types which based on Nitro system but I would like to know the list in a dynamic way with CLI. (for example, using  `aws ec2 describe-instances`).  Is it possible to get Nitro based instance type other than parsing the static page? If so, could you tell me the how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to write a bit of additional code to get that information. `aws ec2 describe-instances` will give you `InstanceType` property. You should use a programming language to parse the JSON, extract `InstanceType` and then call `describe-instances` like so: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-types.html?highlight=nitro

From the JSON you get back, extract `hypervisor`. That'll give you Nitro if the instance is Nitro.

Here's a Python code that might work. I have not tested it fully but you can tweak this to get the results you want.

```
"""List all EC2 instances"""
import boto3

def ec2_connection():
    """Connect to AWS using API"""

    region = 'us-east-2'

    aws_key = 'xxx'
    aws_secret = 'xxx'

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id = aws_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret
    )

    ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name = region)

    return ec2


def get_reservations(ec2):
    """Get a list of instances as a dictionary"""

    response = ec2.describe_instances()

    return response['Reservations']


def process_instances(reservations, ec2):
    """Print a colorful list of IPs and instances"""

    if len(reservations) == 0:
        print('No instance found. Quitting')
        return

    for reservation in reservations:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:

            # get friendly name of the server
            # only try this for mysql1.local server
            friendly_name = get_friendly_name(instance)
            if friendly_name.lower() != 'mysql1.local':
                continue

            # get the hypervisor based on the instance type
            instance_type = get_instance_info(instance['InstanceType'], ec2)

            # print findings
            print(f'{friendly_name} // {instance["InstanceType"]} is {instance_type}')
            break


def get_instance_info(instance_type, ec2):
    """Get hypervisor from the instance type"""

    response = ec2.describe_instance_types(
        InstanceTypes=[instance_type]
    )

    return response['InstanceTypes'][0]['Hypervisor']


def get_friendly_name(instance):
    """Get friendly name of the instance"""

    tags = instance['Tags']
    for tag in tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            return tag['Value']

    return 'Unknown'


def run():
    """Main method to call"""

    ec2 = ec2_connection()
    reservations = get_reservations(ec2)
    process_instances(reservations, ec2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    run()
    print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above answer , the statement "From the JSON you get back, extract hypervisor. That'll give you Nitro if the instance is Nitro " is not longer accurate.

As per the latest [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html),
hypervisor - The hypervisor type of the instance (ovm | xen ). The value xen is used for both Xen and Nitro hypervisors.

Comment: If you're not going to provide an alternative answer, it's probably better to post this correction as a comment instead of a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up, verified working code below:

```
# Get all instance types that run on Nitro hypervisor
import boto3
def get_nitro_instance_types():
    """Get all instance types that run on Nitro hypervisor"""
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = 'us-east-1')
    response = ec2.describe_instance_types(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'hypervisor',
                'Values': [
                    'nitro',
                ]
            },
        ],
    )
    instance_types = []
    for instance_type in response['InstanceTypes']:
        instance_types.append(instance_type['InstanceType'])
    return instance_types

get_nitro_instance_types()
```

Example output as of 12/06/2022 below:

> ['r5dn.8xlarge', 'x2iedn.xlarge', 'r6id.2xlarge', 'r6gd.medium',
> 'm5zn.2xlarge', 'r6idn.16xlarge', 'c6a.48xlarge', 'm5a.16xlarge',
> 'im4gn.2xlarge', 'c6gn.16xlarge', 'c6in.24xlarge', 'r5ad.24xlarge',
> 'r6i.xlarge', 'c6i.32xlarge', 'x2iedn.2xlarge', 'r6id.xlarge',
> 'i3en.24xlarge', 'i3en.12xlarge', 'm5d.8xlarge', 'c6i.8xlarge',
> 'r6g.large', 'm6gd.4xlarge', 'r6a.2xlarge', 'x2iezn.4xlarge',
> 'c6i.large', 'r6in.24xlarge', 'm6gd.xlarge', 'm5dn.2xlarge',
> 'd3en.2xlarge', 'c6id.8xlarge', 'm6a.large', 'is4gen.xlarge',
> 'r6g.8xlarge', 'm6idn.large', 'm6a.2xlarge', 'c6i.4xlarge',
> 'i4i.16xlarge', 'm5zn.6xlarge', 'm5.8xlarge', 'm6id.xlarge',
> 'm5n.16xlarge', 'c6g.16xlarge', 'r5n.12xlarge', 't4g.nano',
> 'm5ad.12xlarge', 'r6in.12xlarge', 'm6idn.12xlarge', 'g5.2xlarge',
> 'trn1.32xlarge', 'x2gd.8xlarge', 'is4gen.4xlarge', 'r6gd.xlarge',
> 'r5a.xlarge', 'r5a.2xlarge', 'c5ad.24xlarge', 'r6a.xlarge',
> 'r6g.medium', 'm6id.12xlarge', 'r6idn.2xlarge', 'c5n.2xlarge',
> 'g5.4xlarge', 'm5d.xlarge', 'i3en.3xlarge', 'r5.24xlarge',
> 'r6gd.2xlarge', 'c5d.large', 'm6gd.12xlarge', 'm6id.2xlarge',
> 'm6i.large', 'z1d.2xlarge', 'm5a.4xlarge', 'm5a.2xlarge',
> 'c6in.xlarge', 'r6id.16xlarge', 'c7g.8xlarge', 'm5dn.12xlarge',
> 'm6gd.medium', 'im4gn.8xlarge', 'm5dn.large', 'c5ad.4xlarge',
> 'r6g.16xlarge', 'c6a.24xlarge', 'c6a.16xlarge']

Answer (score 0):

"""List all EC2 instances"""
import boto3

def ec2_connection():
"""Connect to AWS using API"""

```
region = 'us-east-2'

aws_key = 'xxx'
aws_secret = 'xxx'

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id = aws_key,
    aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret
)

ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name = region)

return ec2
```

def get_reservations(ec2):
"""Get a list of instances as a dictionary"""

```
response = ec2.describe_instances()

return response['Reservations']
```

def process_instances(reservations, ec2):
"""Print a colorful list of IPs and instances"""

```
if len(reservations) == 0:
    print('No instance found. Quitting')
    return

for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:

        # get friendly name of the server
        # only try this for mysql1.local server
        friendly_name = get_friendly_name(instance)
        if friendly_name.lower() != 'mysql1.local':
            continue

        # get the hypervisor based on the instance type
        instance_type = get_instance_info(instance['InstanceType'], ec2)

        # print findings
        print(f'{friendly_name} // {instance["InstanceType"]} is {instance_type}')
        break
```

def get_instance_info(instance_type, ec2):
"""Get hypervisor from the instance type"""

```
response = ec2.describe_instance_types(
    InstanceTypes=[instance_type]
)

return response['InstanceTypes'][0]['Hypervisor']
```

def get_friendly_name(instance):
"""Get friendly name of the instance"""

```
tags = instance['Tags']
for tag in tags:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
        return tag['Value']

return 'Unknown'
```

def run():
"""Main method to call"""

```
ec2 = ec2_connection()
reservations = get_reservations(ec2)
process_instances(reservations, ec2)
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
run()
print('Done')
```